# How can I find corrupt characters in a log file?

Tags: unix

Is there a quick and dirty way to print all lines in a log file containing non-printing characters? Like the line

```
TEST Ò
```

which can be generated by:

```
int main(int arg, char** argv)
{
  char buffer[32];
  buffer[0] = 1234;
  buffer[1] = '\0';
  fprintf(stderr, "TEST %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: We could guess what you need, but please give examples of 'corrupt characters' and 'a bad `printf` call`

Comment: I assume you're referring to non-printing characters, like control-characters?

Comment: Yes, non-printing characters, I've clarified with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep with the perl regular expression option.  You can change the regular expression to target the right range of characters if this is too inclusive or not inclusive enough (maybe tabs are ok? Certain unicode characters might be considered ok?):

```
grep -n -P "[\x01-x\09]|[\x0B-\x0C]|[\x0E-\x1F]|[\x7F-\xFF]" log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
awk -e '!/^[A-Z]*$/ {print $0}' ./test
```

to print all lines with characters that are not withing the specified range.

**Explanation**:

```
awk -e
```

invokes the [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk) program with the following code

```
'!/^[A-Z]*$
```

starts a rule that matches anything that doesn't match (`!`) the regex `^[A-Z]*$`

```
 {print $0}'
```

if the rule is matched, print the whole line

```
 ./test
```

passes the file to operate on.

**Note**: Please note that you might have to adapt the regex to fit your data, as you didn't provide us with enough test data.